# Ожидание загрузки всех библиотек

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница *logic.php*, которая делает выборку из БД.

Есть страница *index.php*, которая Ajax'ом подгружает данные из *logic.php* и выводит их. Здесь я подключаю jQuery и jQuery UI (для анимации цвета).

И когда содержимое загружено (эти шаги я опускаю), я выбираю:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li:first').animate({ 'background-color': "#FF9900", "opacity": "0.5" }, 1900).queue(function() {    
        $(this).css({ 'background': '', "opacity": "" }) 
    })
})
```

Этот код не срабатывает, а если пишу так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li:first').animate({ 'background-color': "#FF9900", "opacity": "0.5" }, 1900).queue(function () {    
            $(this).css({ 'background': '', "opacity": "" }) 
        })
    }, 100);
})
```

То этот код срабатывает.

Как добиться того, чтобы все библиотеки уже были подгружены и мне не приходилось бы прописывать `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вызывать код

```
$('li:first').animate({ 'background-color': "#FF9900", "opacity": "0.5" }, 1900).queue(function() {    
    $(this).css({ 'background': '', "opacity": "" }) 
})
```

не в методе $(document).ready, а после вызова ajax-запроса, который меняет содержимое страницы:

```
$.ajax( "example.php" ).done(function(data){
    //...
    //ТУТ
})
```

Если таких вызовов несколько, то можно оформить ваш код в отдельную функцию и применять ее к новым кускам страницы после загрузки каждого из них.

Answer (score 2):

`$( document ).ready()` выстреливает после загрузки и создания DOM, т.е. голого HTML - набора тэгов. Все внешние скрипты, картинки и шрифты к этому моменту еще не успевают подгрузиться. ПОЛНАЯ загрузка отмечается событием window.onload, вот к нему-то и привязывайтесь:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    //тут анимация ваша 
}
```

Или на JQ:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Альтернативно, можно использовать [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs), чтобы управлять очередностью загрузки и выполнения событий.

Comment: опробывал то что вы пишете,фиг его знает,в общем не работает :(

Comment: @vasily_dumov для того, чтобы ответы точно решали вашу проблему, в вопросе должен быть [код, воссоздающий проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).